# Pick a top item from the fortune of wheel

Tags: javascript, math, svg

I am working with this fortune of wheel (from a pen by Théo Soulie copied to snipped).

I think what question is being picked depends on `picked` variable in `function spin()` in JS code.

Right now it picks the question on the left (where the arrow is) but **I'd like it to pick the question from the top**.

How can I achieve that?

```js
var padding = {
    top: 20,
    right: 40,
    bottom: 0,
    left: 0
  },
  w = 500 - padding.left - padding.right,
  h = 500 - padding.top - padding.bottom,
  r = Math.min(w, h) / 2,
  rotation = 0,
  oldrotation = 0,
  picked = 100000,
  color = d3.scale.category20(); //category20c()
//randomNumbers = getRandomNumbers();



var data = [{
    "label": "Question 1",
    "value": 1,
    "question": "What CSS property is used for specifying the area between the content and its border?"
  }, // padding
  {
    "label": "Question 2",
    "value": 1,
    "question": "What CSS property is used for changing the font?"
  }, //font-family
  {
    "label": "Question 3",
    "value": 1,
    "question": "What CSS property is used for changing the color of text?"
  }, //color
  {
    "label": "Question 4",
    "value": 1,
    "question": "What CSS property is used for changing the boldness of text?"
  }, //font-weight
  {
    "label": "Question 5",
    "value": 1,
    "question": "What CSS property is used for changing the size of text?"
  }, //font-size
  {
    "label": "Question 6",
    "value": 1,
    "question": "What CSS property is used for changing the background color of a box?"
  }, //background-color
  {
    "label": "Question 7",
    "value": 1,
    "question": "Which word is used for specifying an HTML tag that is inside another tag?"
  }, //nesting
  {
    "label": "Question 8",
    "value": 1,
    "question": "Which side of the box is the third number in: margin:1px 1px 1px 1px; ?"
  }, //bottom
  {
    "label": "Question 9",
    "value": 1,
    "question": "What are the fonts that don't have serifs at the ends of letters called?"
  }, //sans-serif
  {
    "label": "Question 10",
    "value": 1,
    "question": "In CSS selectors, what character prefix should one use to specify a class?"
  }, //period

];


var svg = d3.select('#chart')
  .append("svg")
  .data([data])
  .attr("width", w + padding.left + padding.right)
  .attr("height", h + padding.top + padding.bottom);

var container = svg.append("g")
  .attr("class", "chartholder")
  .attr("transform", "translate(" + (w / 2 + padding.left) + "," + (h / 2 + padding.top) + ")");

var vis = container
  .append("g");

var pie = d3.layout.pie().sort(null).value(function(d) {
  return 1;
});

// declare an arc generator function
var arc = d3.svg.arc().outerRadius(r);

// select paths, use arc generator to draw
var arcs = vis.selectAll("g.slice")
  .data(pie)
  .enter()
  .append("g")
  .attr("class", "slice");


arcs.append("path")
  .attr("fill", function(d, i) {
    return color(i);
  })
  .attr("d", function(d) {
    return arc(d);
  });

// add the text
arcs.append("text").attr("transform", function(d) {
    d.innerRadius = 0;
    d.outerRadius = r;
    d.angle = (d.startAngle + d.endAngle) / 2;
    return "rotate(" + (d.angle * 180 / Math.PI - 90) + ")translate(" + (d.outerRadius - 10) + ")";
  })
  .attr("text-anchor", "end")
  .text(function(d, i) {
    return data[i].label;
  });

container.on("click", spin);


function spin(d) {


  var ps = 360 / data.length,
    pieslice = Math.round(1440 / data.length),
    rng = Math.floor((Math.random() * 1440) + 360);

  rotation = (Math.round(rng / ps) * ps);

  picked = Math.round(data.length - (rotation % 360) / ps);
  picked = picked >= data.length ? (picked % data.length) : picked;




  rotation += 90 - Math.round(ps / 2);

  vis.transition()
    .duration(3000)
    .attrTween("transform", rotTween)
    .each("end", function() {

      //mark question as seen
      /* d3.select(".slice:nth-child(" + (picked + 1) + ") path")
           .attr("fill", "#111");*/

      //populate question
      d3.select("#question h1")
        .text(data[picked].label);

      oldrotation = rotation;
    });
}

//make arrow
svg.append("g")
  .attr("transform", "translate(" + (w + padding.left + padding.right) + "," + ((h / 2) + padding.top) + ")")
  .append("path")
  .attr("d", "M-" + (r * .15) + ",0L0," + (r * .05) + "L0,-" + (r * .05) + "Z")
  .style({
    "fill": "black"
  });

//draw spin circle
container.append("circle")
  .attr("cx", 0)
  .attr("cy", 0)
  .attr("r", 10)
  .style({
    "fill": "white",
    "cursor": "pointer"
  });

//spin text
/* container.append("text")
     .attr("x", 0)
     .attr("y", 15)
     .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
     .text("SPIN")
     .style({"font-weight":"bold", "font-size":"30px"});*/


function rotTween(to) {
  var i = d3.interpolate(oldrotation % 360, rotation);
  return function(t) {
    return "rotate(" + i(t) + ")";
  };
}


function getRandomNumbers() {
  var array = new Uint16Array(1000);
  var scale = d3.scale.linear().range([360, 1440]).domain([0, 100000]);

  if (window.hasOwnProperty("crypto") && typeof window.crypto.getRandomValues === "function") {
    window.crypto.getRandomValues(array);
    console.log("works");
  } else {
    //no support for crypto, get crappy random numbers
    for (var i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
      array[i] = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100000) + 1;
    }
  }

  return array;
}
```

```css
text {
  font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 11px;
  pointer-events: none;
}

#chart {
  position: absolute;
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

#question {
  position: absolute;
  width: 400px;
  height: 500px;
  top: 0;
  left: 520px;
}

#question h1 {
  font-size: 50px;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  position: absolute;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  top: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translate(0, -50%);
  transform: translate(0, -50%);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Wheel of Fortune Bingo</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="chart"></div>
  <div id="question">
    <h1></h1>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Can you please clarify what you mean by "on the left" and "from the top". The code is picking a random item from the data array (the questions), what would you like it to do?

Comment: Right now it picks item from the wheel from where the arrow is (on the left).

Comment: you want the code to pick question in top while arrow still in left ? and also what top is that ? there is two questions in top

Comment: It's a CSS problem to change arrow's position - I can do that. Even if I changed the arrow's position with CSS it would still picks question on the left (understandably).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it! It was enough to change a starting point of the wheel.

Change this line from:

```
rotation += 90 - Math.round(ps/2);
```

To:

```
rotation += 0 - Math.round(ps/2);
```

Comment: or you can change picked to :
picked = data.length -  ( (rotation%360)/36 );
after :
rotation += 90 - Math.round(ps/2);